# Longest item in array

Tags: ruby

Is there an easier way than below to find the longest item in an array?

```
arr = [
    [0,1,2],
    [0,1,2,3],
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,2,3]
]

longest_row = []
@rows.each { |row| longest_row = row if row.length > longest_row.length }

p longest_row # => [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Edit: The former versions were a little wrong and unclear concerning the version numbers*

Starting with Ruby versions 1.9 and 1.8.7+, the `Enumerable#max_by` method is available:

```
@rows = arr.max_by{|a| a.length}
```

`max_by` executes the given block for each object in arr and then returns that object which has had the largest result.

In simple cases like this, where the block only consists of one method name and some variable noise, there is actually no need for an explicit block. It is possible make use of the `Symbol#to_proc` method and avoid the block variable altogether, making this:

```
@rows = arr.max_by(&:length)
```

Earlier versions of Ruby lack both the `#to_proc` and the `#max_by` method. Therefore, we need to explicitly give our actual comparison and use `Enumerable#max`.

```
@rows = arr.max{|c1, c2| c1.length <=> c2.length}
```

*Thanks to all comments for clarification.*

Comment: And of course with Ruby 1.8.7+, 1.9 or ActiveSupport, that would just be `arr.max_by(&:length)`.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that `Enumerable#max_by` doesn't exist in 1.8.6 anyway.

Comment: In 1.8.6, you can do `arr.max {|a, b| a.length <=> b.length}`.

Comment: wouldn't `@rows = arr.max_by{ |a| a.length }` work in 1.9 as well as 1.8.7 and above? (According to [the docs](http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.9/classes/Enumerable.html#M000746))

Answer (score 1):

arr.inject{|longest,current| longest.length > current.length ? longest : current}

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array based on length and then pull the longest.

```
sorted_rows = @rows.sort{|x,y| y.length<=>x.length}
longest_row = sorted_rows.first
```

Not really that efficient, but it's an alternative. If you didn't want to use a new array and didn't care about the ordering in the @rows array you could just use the sort! method.